# how to use fadeIn with display=inline-block

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

I try to fadeIn a div which (should) have a display inline-block.
It seems the fadeIn method assumes only display=block.
Is there a way to change that behavior?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

From a combination of what I read above, this is the best I got:

```
    $(div).css({
        opacity: 0,
        display: 'inline-block'     
    }).animate({opacity:1},600);
```

Comment: Just great man.. Thanks

Answer (score 22):

If you use [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)?

```
$("div").fadeIn().css("display","inline-block");
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but I have a feeling it might cause the element to jump around a bit, as it would be changed to `display:block;` during the animation, and then back to `display:inline-block` after the animation had finished. So I don't think it's going to work. Might be worth trying out though, so +1 anyway.

Comment: @Spudley I thought is also and tried it with `position:inline` instead `position:inline-block` to see if shows it first as `display:block` but it didn't. http://jsfiddle.net/6DcY9/ Of course depending on the other code this may happen

Comment: I'm doing a `fadeIn("fast").css({'display':'inline-block'})` and it doesn't cause my layout to jump around at all. I think it sets the display property before the fadeIn finishes.  Additionally, since IE7 doesn't know how to interpret inline-block, I'm checking whether `html` has a class of `ie7` then setting `.css({'display':'inline','zoom':'1'})` instead.

Comment: @Spudley - the `.css("display","inline-block")` is not queued to run after the animation, it happens right when the animation begins

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest putting an extra element layer inside the `inline-block` element, and fading that in instead.

```
<div style='display:inline-block;'>
    <div id='fadmein'>....</div>
</div>

$('#fademein').fadeIn();
```

I know it's extra markup, but it's probably the most pragmatic solution to the problem.

The alternative would be to use JQuery's `animate()` method to change the opacity, rather than using `fadeIn()`. This would only change the `opacity` property; so the `display` property would be untouched.

Comment: Depending on how you've set up the content, this may not be the best looking solution, but this is probably the easiest to implement and works surprisingly well. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/animate-inline-elements) in the jQuery Forums, the suggested solution is to change its ´display´ property to `block` and floating it.

Comment: gosh no. if you're using `inline-block`, it's because you're trying to avoid floating.

Comment: I agree. But I think it's a relevant link to provide